# HTML5 Video Controls not working with CSS transform

Tags: html5-video, css-transforms

I have an HTML5 Video element inside a container defining a fixed height and an `overflow: auto` style so I'm able to scroll inside the container.
Additionally there is a `transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px);` Style, required because of an animation.

When I hit the settings icon (the three dots - available in Google Chrome) of the video controls, the context menu is shown somewhere else (I guess) and the container scrolls back to the top. I found the cause of all this is the `transform`, but I did not find a way to "reset" this.

See the attached JSFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/yjL1ndh5/

Can someone
a) explain to me why exactly this happens and
b) suggest a fix for the css code?